# How to create a hyperlinked cross-reference to an unnumbered section-level header?

Tags: cross-referencing, hyperlink

In the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
The proof of \cref{th:fermat} may be found in the \ref{sec:appendix-omittedproofs}

\section*{Appendix: omitted proofs}\label{sec:appendix-omittedproofs}
\end{document}
```

I would like where there is `\ref{sec:appendix-omittedproofs}`, to have "Appendix" written and highlighted with a hyperlink pointing to `\section*{Appendix: omitted proofs}`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the appendix section to be unnumbered, you *cannot* use the `\label`-`\ref` or `\label`-`\cref` mechanism to create the desired link. (The `\label` directive latches on to the most recently incremented counter variable. Since the counter named `section` is, by design, not incremented when executing `\section*`, `\label` cannot reliably create an association with the unnumbered sectioning header.)

An alternative is the `\hypertarget`-`\hyperlink` machinery, which is provided by the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
The proof of everything may be found in the \hyperlink{abc}{Appendix}.

\section*{\hypertarget{abc}{Appendix: Omitted proofs}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple yet effective work around:
You can redefine the section counter to be "Appendix #:" and simply use `\ref{}` to get the name:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
The proof of \cref{th:fermat} may be found in the \ref{sec:appendix-omittedproofs}.
\section{Bar}
Section numbering works as usual until here.
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \alph{section}:}
\section{omitted proofs}\label{sec:appendix-omittedproofs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but then I would have the redefine the section counter after the Appendix (because I have normal section afterwards)?